# Unity5 не хочет компилировать APK файл. Что же делать?

Tags: android, unity3d, android-sdk, apk

Unity 5 выводит несмолкаемую ошибку о том, что что-то не так с моим Android SDK. Пробовал много способов решения, но ничего не помогло. Может вы поможете? Вот текст ошибки:
"Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот ссылка на туториал на YouTube: [Тык!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xH3IyvtsLuc "Та самая ссылка")

Answer (score 1):

Нужно проверить все пути к SDK, JDK, NDK. Может где то ошибка. У самого такое было. И еще нужно пути прописать пути в переменную окружения PATH. Unity пишет что у вас неправильный путь к SDK.